# Problems after migrating from personal profile to a page on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I'm not sure if this is a right place to ask, but I don't know where else can I look for support

So I've used a new facebook feature which lets you migrate from a personal profile to a fan page. It saves all of the friends and a profile picture. Now, every time a photo gets commented, I get an email with a notification and a link to see the comment. But when I click it, I'm being redirected Basic Information tab in "Edit Info", and so I don't know what was commented.

I'm being redirected to the same Basic Information tab when I log in or click on the Facebook logo.

Comment: I'm having this exact problem and I tried adding another admin to the page, but still encounter the same issues. Would you mind elaborating on

Comment: You have to login as the added admin as of now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had to assign another admin to the page, because the one that migrated (the same account split into an admin account(which was deleted) and the page itself). The problem arose, because the admin account was deleted after creating a page.